# custom error message in player for livestream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I have a react code as shown below which renders player. In the code below, if the condition is true then the code for the ReactJWPlayer is called.

```
const player = ()=> {
    if(condition) {
        return (
            <ReactJWPlayer
                onPlaylist={[props.playlist]}
                onPlay={() => onPlay()}
                autoPlay={props.autoplay}
                isMuted={false}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

What I want to achieve is, I want to display a `custom error message` if livestream ends abruptly. Right now, I am seeing:

```
This video file cannot be played 

(Error Code: 232011)
```

[image]

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the code above so that I can replace an error message above with the following error message:

`Video will be available soon`.

Comment: Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68322358/display-custom-error-message-in-jw-player/68368343#

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onError` prop to capture all "media" errors. Setup errors can be caught using `onSetupError` prop.
(P.S. In newer versions of library you should be able to use `onError` to catch both error types) Here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jw-player-example-forked-tof18?file=/src/App.js) how to handle error with code `102404`:

```
import ReactJWPlayer from "react-jw-player";

export default function App() {
  
  const setupErrorHandler= (error) => {
    console.log("Setup error");
    console.log(error);
    if (error && error.code === 102404) {
      window.alert(error.message);
    }
    //here you write similar if condition to check if error has error 
      code 232404
    if(error && error.code === 232404){
        //do something..
    }
  };

 const mediaErrorHandler= (error) => {
    console.log("Media error");
    console.log(error);
    //handle error
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="jw-video-container"
        data-mediaid="TAITbudl"
        style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
      >
        <ReactJWPlayer
          playerId="TAITbudl"
          playerScript="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/j9BLvpMc.js"
          playlist="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/playlists/vXggtmeu"
         
          onError={(event) => mediaErrorHandler(event)}
          onSetupError={(event) => setupErrorHandler(event)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note : All `jwplayer` errors have this form :

```
 {
      "code": 104153,
      "message": "Sorry, the video player failed to load.",
      "sourceError": { Error object | null },
      "type": "setupError"
    }
```

See [documentation](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-errors-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Appreciate your help on that. I am wondering if you can give me some pointers what I need to write inside that method.

Comment: When the error code is 232011, I want to display "Video will be available soon" on the player. 

`if(error && error.code === 232011){
 
}`

I am wondering what I need to write inside the if block so that "Video will be available soon" on the player will be displayed when error code is `232011`.

Comment: One way to achieve that is to get reference of jwplplayer inside error handler method like this : const player = window.jwplayer(playerId) and then call load() method and 
pass it your custom error mesage. (see https://www.jwplayer.com/developers/web-player-demos/custom-error/)  Other way is to wrap ReactJWPlayer component iside div, get reference to that div inside error handler method, and change innerHTML attribute to display your custom error paragraph. You can look at this example : https://codepen.io/fdambrosio/pen/vmbPEK

Answer (score -1):

Somehow using VPN of other countries solved the issue.