# display custom error message in a live Player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I have a **react code** as shown below which renders player on page load. The code goes inside the if block only if the condition is true.

```
const player = ()=> {
    if(condition) {
        return (
            <ReactJWPlayer
                playlist={[props.playlist]}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**  For the error code `232011`, I am seeing the following error message:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
This video file cannot be played
(Error Code: 232011)
```

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the react code above so that I can replace the above error message with the following one in the player.

```
Video will be available soon
```

Comment: Critical details are missing from the question. For example, we need to know the structure of `ReactJWPlayer` component, in order to figure out the changes to make.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem online in codesandbox?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky We did `npm install react-jw-player.js` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jw-player

Comment: I think I have to use `jwplayer().on('error') and  jwplayer().on('setupError')` methods, found in our Developer Documentation. 
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#jwplayeronerror but I am not sure how I can integrate in the current code structure which I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`intl.{lang}.errors`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference#intllangerrors-object) object. This object localizes the error messages displayed in the player.

In order to configure [`intl.{lang}.errors`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference#intllangerrors-object), you will have to use [`customProps`](https://github.com/micnews/react-jw-player#optional-configuration-props) option exposed by react-jw-player to be applied directly to the JW Player instance.

You can stick with `en` only, or add additional language support depending on your use-case.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import ReactJWPlayer from "react-jw-player";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const jwPlayerRef = useRef();

  const myErrorHandler = (err) => {
    console.log(err);
   // Find the Node where error message is shown
    const errorNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(
      jwPlayerRef.current
    ).getElementsByClassName("jw-error-text");
    // If the error node exists, replace both message and code
    if (errorNode && errorNode.length)
      errorNode[0].innerText = "Custom Error Message";
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="jw-video-container"
        data-mediaid="TAITbudl"
        style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
      >
        <ReactJWPlayer
          ref={jwPlayerRef}
          playerId="TAITbudl"
          playerScript="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/j9BLvpMc.js"
          playlist="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/123"
          onError={myErrorHandler}
          onSetupError={myErrorHandler}
          customProps={{ // <= Official way to override the error message
            intl: {
              en: {
                errors: {
                  badConnection:
                    "This video cannot be played because of a problem with your internet connection.",
                  cantLoadPlayer: "Sorry, the video player failed to load.",
                  cantPlayInBrowser:
                    "The video cannot be played in this browser.",
                  cantPlayVideo: "This is my custom error Message",
                  errorCode: "Code - ",
                  liveStreamDown:
                    "The live stream is either down or has ended.",
                  protectedContent:
                    "There was a problem providing access to protected content.",
                  technicalError:
                    "This video cannot be played because of a technical error."
                }
              }
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React-JW-Player Custom Error Message]

> The `intl` object allows you to add new language translations, [...] - [Docs](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference#internationalization)

Note that `getElementsByClassName("jw-error-text")` is a hack, and if JW Player decided to change the class name, or obfuscate it, this hack will break.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about intl object. I have read the docs of it and it seems to very useful object when it comes to adding new language translations. I opened the sandbox and I can see the `error code` as well in the 
player beneath the text message. Is there any way I can get rid of `(Code-:102400)` line as well ?

Comment: I could not find any such API exposed by JW Player which allows to hide the error code. If you take a look the the JW player script file, you can see that the error code is from an internal API and not customizable. That said, I've updated the answer and the code-sandbox to get rid of the error code.

Comment: Ok, make sense. Thanks for letting me know. I am wondering what is the use of `ref={jwPlayerRef}` in `<ReactJWPlayer` ?

Comment: It's for manipulation of DOM directly.https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Hi, I am following on my question. What are the list of error codes covered by the property *cantPlayVideo* ? I can't find any information in the [documentation](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference#intllangerrors-object)